# How do I solve this error "Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function 'updateTimer()'", trying to make countdown timer in swift 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    let eggTimes = ["Soft": 300, "Medium": 420, "Hard": 720]
    
    var secondsRemaining = 60
    
    
    @IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let hardness = sender.currentTitle!
        
        secondsRemaining = eggTimes[hardness]!
        
        
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        
        func updateTimer() {
            if secondsRemaining > 0 {
                print("\(secondsRemaining) seconds.")
                secondsRemaining -= 1
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I am taking this Udemy course where it seems to be working fine but on my system, it is not working at all.

Comment: `func updateTimer()` is INSIDE `@IBAction func hardnessSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {}`. Check the `{` and `}`. Put it outside.

Comment: Move `func updateTimer() {` out of your IBAction method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action method must be on the top level of the class (the `eggTimes` level) and must be marked as `@objc`.

A more convenient solution is the (underestimated) closure-based API of `Timer`

Replace

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func updateTimer() {
    if secondsRemaining > 0 {
        print("\(secondsRemaining) seconds.")
        secondsRemaining -= 1
    }
}
```

with

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [unowned self] timer in 
    if self.secondsRemaining > 0 {
        print("\(self.secondsRemaining) seconds.")
        self.secondsRemaining -= 1
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr @vadian !